# MySQL set ID of primary child with constraint

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have two MySQL tables where the primary relationship between the two is one-to-many. I also need a one-to-one relationship in the parent_table with the ID for the primary record from the child_table. You can kind of think of it as like a dad having lots of kids but having one kid that's his favorite ;P. Is it possible to setup a DB constraint such that a parent can have the ID of a child only if that child is a child of the parent?

```
parent_table (One)
  id: Primary Key
  primary_child_id: {ID from child table}

child_table (Many)
  id: Primary Key
  parent_table: {ID from parent table}
```

EDIT: The primary child is optional and child records will only be created for an already existing parent. The child_table can certainly be created after the parent_table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it's tricky.

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  primary_child_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (primary_child_id) REFERENCES child_table(id)
);

CREATE TABLE child_table (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent_table(id)
);
```

This is a circular reference, so you end up having a chicken-and-egg problem.

I resolve this by making the parent_table.primary_child_id a NULLABLE column, so you can create a parent row even before there are any child rows to reference. If you use NULL in the foreign key column on a given row, it's not a violation of the constraint.

The other tricky part is defining the tables in a circular reference relationship, when creating them as new tables. So you have to leave out one or the other constraint definition until both tables are defined, and then ALTER TABLE to add the missing constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  primary_child_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE child_table (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent_table(id)
);

ALTER TABLE parent_TABLE
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (primary_child_id) REFERENCES child_table(id);
```

---

*the parent [shouldn't be allowed to] have a favorite child that isn't his.*

Okay, if you need the parent to reference *only* child records that reference itself:

```
ALTER TABLE child_table
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (parent_id, id);

ALTER TABLE parent_TABLE
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (id, primary_child_id) REFERENCES child_table(parent_id, id);
```

If you create the index in the child table before creating the foreign key, then the foreign key can use that index instead of creating a redundant index.

Comment: Or just disable foreign key checks and create at least one child row when you make the parent row.

Comment: Yes that works too, but you may not know the child id until it gets created, so you have to use NULL anyway, and then UPDATE after you create the child record. Also in some apps, the child records don't get created in the same session, but are created some time later, so you'd want the NULL to stay around for a while.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, a trigger which raises a [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) should work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER parent_child BEFORE INSERT ON parent_table 
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM child_table WHERE id = new.id)
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'   
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Constraint failed';
    ENF IF; 
END; 
$$
```

I'm not sure how you're choosing which table should get a record first when each depends on the other.  So instead of this trigger you might prefer to write a stored procedure to create the "primary" relationship and validate it also with a SIGNAL.

Comment: The parent will definitely exist first and may not have any children, The primary child is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You want the child's ID changes/deletions to cascade up to the parent's "favorite child" field, and the parent's ID changes/deletions to cascade down to all its children.

Your parent table should have `id` and `favchild`, where `id` is its primary key index. You would then make a foreign key for favchild that references the child table's primary key.

On the child table, you would make a parent field with a foreign key that references the parent table's id. Then you can have many children with one parent, and one child is the parent's favorite.

However, in order to do this, you need to disable foreign key constraints when you create the parent, because you will need to create at least one child at the same time.

**Edit**
 If the parent must make sure favchild is actually a child: Since the parent row is added first, it would only be updated with favchild by some application logic. In which case you can do the check during that update. The only constraint from that point on would be if favchild were to change parents. So for that your parent table could have two extra columns instead of one: favchild_id and favchild_parent_id. Make those a combined index, with a combined foreign key that references the two columns of the child. ON UPDATE SET NULL. The only drawback here is if the child's ID were to change, it would also be nulled instead of cascaded to the parent.

Comment: That doesn't constrain the parent to only only children that have the ID of the parent. That is how I have it implemented now. The problem is that the parent can have a favorite child that isn't his.